# Abrir página depois do carregamento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou pensando em fazer isto utilizando jQuery e utilizei alguns métodos já disponíveis na internet mas não estão funcionando. Tentei modificá-lo mais acho que estou fazendo isto da maneira errada.

O que eu estou querendo fazer: a página deve abrir depois de carregar totalmente, para que ao abrir uma página qualquer tenha todo o conteúdo já disponível após o seu carregamento.

O código:

```
  body{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;}

    <div id="bloquear" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#333;"></div>


    function liberar(){
        document.getElementById('bloquear').style.display='none';
        document.body.style.overflow='scroll';
    }
<body onload="liberar">
<div id="bloquear" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#FFFFF;"></div>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender o que é "isto" que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: @bfavaretto desculpe se não expliquei do modo correto, o que eu estou querendo fazer: a página deve abrir depois de carregar totalmente, para que ao abrir uma página qualquer tenha todo o conteúdo já disponível após o seu carregamento.

Comment: the flash, por favor, prefira editar a pergunta em vez de esclarecer nos comentários.

Comment: @brasofilo ok,desculpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigindo seu código:

```
<style  type="text/css">
  body {overflow: hidden;}
  #bloquear {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#333;}
  #conteudo {display: none;)
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#bloquear').hide();
          $('#conteudo').show();
     });

</script>

<div id="bloquear">AQUI O QUE APARECE ENQUANTO NÃO CARREGOU</div>

<div id="conteudo">SEU CONTEUDO AQUI DENTRO!!!</div>
```

Ele só carrega a página depois de carregar todos os scripts (menos imagens).
Ele não é muito funcional...

Você também pode usar o load ao invés do ready!

Comment: coloquei um outro exemplo...mas depende de como o CSS dele estiver, no exemplo que ele colocou tá muito confuso..

Comment: @user3230262 aqui está uma página onde será utilizada este método de carregamento: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/DHctJ

Comment: @theflash fiz a correção no seu código, espero que seja isso...

Comment: obrigado, apenas não entendi um ponto se eu estiver com uma única div "wrapper" que seria a div pai, o que devo fazer para esconder e demostrar todo conteúdo apenas após o carregamento de uma página, tudo isto de uma só vez?

Comment: você precisa criar a div que vai aparecer enquanto a página não é carregada e deixar a div "wrapper" com display:none para ela aparecer somente quando a página estiver carregada, é exatamente a resposta que eu postei, só falta vc modificar para suas preferencias, lembrando que ele não espera as imagens carregarem, somente os scripts...

Comment: isto esclarece a minha dúvida. obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui fica uma resposta tardia pois a resposta aceite não explica qual o problema que tinha no seu código e acrescenta jQuery quando a solução não é necessáriamente essa.

Tem alguns problemas no seu código:

**O primeiro** é que CSS e JavaScript precisam de tags de HTML para o browser conseguir interpretar esse código como o que ele é e não HTML. Ou seja, em vez deste pedaço:

```
body{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;}

<div id="bloquear" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#333;"></div>

function liberar(){
    document.getElementById('bloquear').style.display='none';
    document.body.style.overflow='scroll';
}
<body onload="liberar">
```

deve ter assim: (com o javascript dentro de tags `<script>`)

```
<style>
body{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;}
</style>

<div id="bloquear" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#333;"></div>
<script>
function liberar(){
    document.getElementById('bloquear').style.display='none';
    document.body.style.overflow='scroll';
}
</script>
<body onload="liberar">
```

**Outro problema** é que a declaração do inicio do `body` ocerre depois de já ter aparecido HTML na página. Isto é inválido. A tag `<body>` diz ao browser que alí começa o corpo da págna e não pode haver HTML fora do body. Assim esta linha:

```
<div id="bloquear" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%; background:#333;"></div>
```

deve ser inserida depois da tag `<body onload="liberar">`

**Outro problema** é que a função liberar não vai ser corrida se não acrescentar `()` no fim. Ou seja `<body onload="liberar()">`. Dê uma olhada aqui (http://jsfiddle.net/sFms7/) teste retirar os `()` e carregue em "Run", vai ver que a função não corre. Isto porque JavaScript dentro de HTML comporta-se de maneira diferente. Esse ponteiro para a função só vai ser lido/parsed quando o `onload` fôr chamado.

**O ultimo problema** é o posicionamento da função `liberar`. Aqui tem duas opções. Ou coloca dentro da tag `<head>` (que falta no seu código) juntamente com o `<style>`, ou então coloca no final do `body`, exatamente antes de `</body>`. Uma vez que é somente uma declaração de função é indiferente onde coloca, desde que tenha as tags de HTML correctas.

### Como o seu código devia estar (exemplo online): http://jsfiddle.net/8Tj23/

(teste retirar `()` a seguir a liberar para ver o código a falhar esconder a div)

Comment: ok cara, obrigado.